# Using sorted() for sorting tuples by first value from every tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I need to sort list of tuples by first value of each tuple. I have code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a= np.array([7.33442355e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 6.29090705e-02, 4.11437985e-02, 1.46726854e-02,
       1.41064835e-02, 1.48742809e-02, 1.42575993e-02, 3.66158981e-01,
       5.64191792e-02, 1.08792957e-01, 5.33510773e-02, 1.03114883e-02,
       1.64780994e-01, 6.02803867e-05, 1.96041560e-03, 2.85647464e-03])


b= ['longitude',
    'some_var',
    'latitude',
    'housing_median_age',
    'total_rooms',
    'total_bedrooms',
    'population',
    'households',
    'median_income',
    'rooms_per_hhold',
    'pop_per_hhold',
    'bedrooms_per_room',
    '<1H OCEAN',
    'INLAND',
    'ISLAND',
    'NEAR BAY',
    'NEAR OCEAN']

x=sorted(zip(a, b), reverse=True)
```

content of `x`: looks like:

```
 [(0.366158981, 'median_income'),
 (0.164780994, 'INLAND'),
 (0.108792957, 'pop_per_hhold'),
 (0.0733442355, 'longitude'),
 (0.0629090705, 'latitude'),
 (0.0564191792, 'rooms_per_hhold'),
 (0.0533510773, 'bedrooms_per_room'),
 (0.0411437985, 'housing_median_age'),
 (0.0148742809, 'population'),
 (0.0146726854, 'total_rooms'),
 (0.0142575993, 'households'),
 (0.0141064835, 'total_bedrooms'),
 (0.0103114883, '<1H OCEAN'),
 (0.00285647464, 'NEAR OCEAN'),
 (0.0019604156, 'NEAR BAY'),
 (6.02803867e-05, 'ISLAND'),
 (0.0, 'some_var')]
```

I need output to look like:

```
 [(0.0, 'some_var'),
 (6.02803867e-05, 'ISLAND'),
 (0.0019604156, 'NEAR BAY'),
 (0.00285647464, 'NEAR OCEAN'),
 (0.0103114883, '<1H OCEAN'),
 (0.0141064835, 'total_bedrooms'),
 (0.0142575993, 'households'),
 (0.0146726854, 'total_rooms'),
 (0.0148742809, 'population'),
 (0.0411437985, 'housing_median_age'),
 (0.0533510773, 'bedrooms_per_room'),
 (0.0564191792, 'rooms_per_hhold'),
 (0.0629090705, 'latitude'),
 (0.0733442355, 'longitude'),
 (0.108792957, 'pop_per_hhold'),
 (0.164780994, 'INLAND'),
 (0.366158981, 'median_income')]
```

Comment: Why should `6.02803867e-05` be first? Because of the exponent, it's a very small value, not the highest.

Comment: `import operator` and  `lst.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0))`

Comment: @Barmar You are right. How can I miss it that it was in scientific notation? Thank you very much for your comment!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That's not necessary. Tuples are ordered lexicographically, so it sorts by the first element by default.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, correct. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lambda expression:

```
lst =  [(0.366158981, 'median_income'),
 (0.164780994, 'INLAND'),
 (0.108792957, 'pop_per_hhold'),
 (0.0733442355, 'longitude'),
 (0.0629090705, 'latitude'),
 (0.0564191792, 'rooms_per_hhold'),
 (0.0533510773, 'bedrooms_per_room'),
 (0.0411437985, 'housing_median_age'),
 (0.0148742809, 'population'),
 (0.0146726854, 'total_rooms'),
 (0.0142575993, 'households'),
 (0.0141064835, 'total_bedrooms'),
 (0.0103114883, '<1H OCEAN'),
 (0.00285647464, 'NEAR OCEAN'),
 (0.0019604156, 'NEAR BAY'),
 (6.02803867e-05, 'ISLAND'),
 (0.0, 'some_var')]

lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])
print(lst)
```

This yields

```
[(0.0, 'some_var'), (6.02803867e-05, 'ISLAND'), (0.0019604156, 'NEAR BAY'), (0.00285647464, 'NEAR OCEAN'), (0.0103114883, '<1H OCEAN'), (0.0141064835, 'total_bedrooms'), (0.0142575993, 'households'), (0.0146726854, 'total_rooms'), (0.0148742809, 'population'), (0.0411437985, 'housing_median_age'), (0.0533510773, 'bedrooms_per_room'), (0.0564191792, 'rooms_per_hhold'), (0.0629090705, 'latitude'), (0.0733442355, 'longitude'), (0.108792957, 'pop_per_hhold'), (0.164780994, 'INLAND'), (0.366158981, 'median_income')]
```

Or - with `reverse = True`:

```
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
print(lst)
```

Which would yield

```
[(0.366158981, 'median_income'), (0.164780994, 'INLAND'), (0.108792957, 'pop_per_hhold'), (0.0733442355, 'longitude'), (0.0629090705, 'latitude'), (0.0564191792, 'rooms_per_hhold'), (0.0533510773, 'bedrooms_per_room'), (0.0411437985, 'housing_median_age'), (0.0148742809, 'population'), (0.0146726854, 'total_rooms'), (0.0142575993, 'households'), (0.0141064835, 'total_bedrooms'), (0.0103114883, '<1H OCEAN'), (0.00285647464, 'NEAR OCEAN'), (0.0019604156, 'NEAR BAY'), (6.02803867e-05, 'ISLAND'), (0.0, 'some_var')]
```

---

As [**@Barmar**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) correctly points out, you do not even need a lambda expression, so `lst = sorted(lst)` will totally do.
You can check it with:

```
lst1 = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x[0])
lst2 = sorted(lst)
assert lst1 == lst2
```

Comment: You don't need a lambda expression. tuples are compared lexicographically, so it automatically compares the first element first.